# Polymer app-router problems

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

Hopefully somebody can help me better understanding using app-router with Polymer. I have the following files - index.html, app.html and updates.html.

Everything is working as it should with the main layout appearing when I navigate to the root of the domain but nothing appears in the content area where I am trying to render the contents of the updates.html file using the app-router element.

Any help is much appreciated

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="elements/app.html">
</head>

<body fullbleed unresolved>
  <example-app></example-app>
</body> 
</html>
```

**app.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-router/app-router.html">

<polymer-element name="example-app">
  <template>
    <core-scaffold id="scaffoldPanel">
      <core-header-panel navigation flex>
        <core-toolbar id="navheader" class="tall">
          <img class="middle profile" src="../images/main-carer.png">
        </core-toolbar>
      </core-header-panel>

      <core-toolbar tool flex>
        <div id="main-title" flex><a href="index.html">Example App</a></div>
          <core-icon icon="search"></core-icon>
      </core-toolbar>

      <div class="content">
        <app-router>
          <app-route path="/" import="elements/updates.html" element="app-updates"></app-route>
        </app-router>
      </div>

    </core-scaffold>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**updates.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="app-updates">
  <template>
      <div vertical layout style="height:50px;">
         <div flex class="home-update-menu"><h4>UPDATES</h4></div>
      </div>

      <div>Updates appear here</div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Did you got it to work? Which version of Polymer where you using?